# HTTP 404 Not Found In DotNetNuke (DNN) Publish

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, dotnetnuke

I created an DNN (version 7) website in IIS in port 3535 and I installed DNN. Then I created an empty solution. I added the website to a project and then I ran the project. It works fine in visual studio, but when I `Publish` from website and create another website in IIS for published folder in port 3737 and browse `localhost:3737` I get the following error in all browsers:

```
HTTP 404 Not Found In DotNetNuke
```

So in summary I have 2 sites:

1- localhost:3535 works fine.

2- localhost:3737 ***doesn't work***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely need to add another "portal alias".

It isn't recommended that you try to run DNN using ports, a full version of IIS using a website would be far easier to manage.

Comment: I am not create multi site in dnn. I want to publish site and use it for test. I want to keep orginal dnn untouched.

Comment: When you say "publish" what do you mean? Publish to a production server? The common approach is to backup/restore, if you want to "transfer" a DNN site from one to another.

Comment: When I say publish i mean's in visual studio i right clicked on website project and then I select `Publish Web Site` to create an release of website. I use this published website in port 3737.

Comment: My statement still stands, dnn didn't publish like other applications

Comment: I i just copy (and not publish) website project to port 3737, the problem still exist and does not go away.

Comment: Have you added the Portal Alias for the new address/port into the copied Database?

Comment: I did not copied database for new one. I have shared database in sql server an I use sql server authentication. But I have added an alias site before i getting publish.